# Convert JSON data into dynamic table using HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, dynamic, html-table

I have been searching the solution to my problem for four days, and I still can't solve it.

I want to convert a JSON string data (from an URL) into a dynamic table, using JQuery and JavaScript.

I have to load the JSON string using the `jQuery.getJSON()` function. 
I don't know how to combine those two things together.

I've been searching for forever and I still don't understand it. Sorry if I sound really stupid but I just can't make something out of it. Can someone please help me?

This is my code:

```
<html>
<head>
<h1> Inventory List </h1>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://wt.ops.few.vu.nl/api/--------"></script>
</head>

<body>
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
    $.getJSON(http://wt.ops.few.vu.nl/api/-------,
    function (json) {
        var tr;
        for (var i = 0; i < json.length; i++) {
            tr = $('<tr/>');
            tr.append("<td>" + json[i].category + "</td>");
            tr.append("<td>" + json[i].name + "</td>");
            tr.append("<td>" + json[i].amount + "</td>");
            tr.append("<td>" + json[i].location + "</td>");
            tr.append("<td>" + json[i].date + "</td>");
            $('#table').append(tr);
        }
    });
});

</script>

<table id= "table">
  <tr>
    <th> Name of product</th>
    <th> Category</th>
    <th> Amount</th>
    <th> Location</th>
    <th> Date</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td> </td>
    <td> </td>
    <td> </td>
    <td> </td>
    <td> </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td> </td>
    <td> </td>
    <td> </td>
    <td> </td>
    <td> </td> 
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td> </td>
    <td> </td>
    <td> </td>
    <td> </td> 
    <td> </td>
  </tr>
</table>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Is wt.ops.few.vu.nl your domain? If not, you have to use jsonp not json.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Your code looks good at a glance. What errors do you get or what specifically is not working?

Comment: Also you may want to include some sample JSON data that can be used for testing.

Comment: I see syntax issue too: `.getJSON('http://wt.ops.few.vu.nl/api/--------', function(json){});` Must wrap URL quotes.

Answer (score 2):

I would advise using JSONP like so: https://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/0trde6es/5/

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  getData();

  function getData() {
    $.ajax({
      url: 'https://jsfiddle.net/echo/jsonp/',
      method: 'GET',
      dataType: "jsonp",
      error: function(xhr, status, error) {
        console.log(status, error);
      },
      success: function(json) {
        var tr;
        $.each(json, function(k, v) {
          tr = $("<tr></tr>");
          tr.append("<td>" + v.name + "</td>");
          tr.append("<td>" + v.category + "</td>");
          tr.append("<td>" + v.amount + "</td>");
          tr.append("<td>" + v.location + "</td>");
          tr.append("<td>" + v.date + "</td>");
          $("#invList").append(tr);
        });
      }
    });
  }
});
```

Since the site may not be on the same domain, and is not using HTTPS, I created the result data in `a1` for testing. I used the following test data:

```
[{"category": "Fruit", "name": "Banana", "amount": 15, "location": "Amsterdam", "date": "2014-10-05", "id": 13844}, {"category": "Fruit", "name": "Apple", "amount": 58, "location": "Amsterdam", "date": "2014-02-05", "id": 13845}, {"category": "Furniture", "name": "Chair", "amount": 3, "location": "Hilversum", "date": "2014-12-10", "id": 13846}, {"category": "Furniture", "name": "Table", "amount": 5, "location": "Rotterdam", "date": "2011-07-13", "id": 13847}]
```

Using `$.each()` is just a faster way of handling object data. There is nothing wrong with your `for()` loop and may work better depending on your needs.

Comment: Thanks so much for your answer! I found the first answer to my question a bit easier to comprehend (due to my lack of insight in webtechnology) but thank you very much for helping me.

Comment: @Webstudent glad to hear that. If you feel like it, you should mark one of them as the answer or Upvote either.

Answer (score 0):

This should work

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
<h1> Inventory List </h1>
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
    $.getJSON('http://wt.ops.few.vu.nl/api/--------',
    function (json) {
        var tr;
        for (var i = 0; i < json.length; i++) {
            tr = $('<tr/>');
            tr.append("<td>" + json[i].category + "</td>");
            tr.append("<td>" + json[i].name + "</td>");
            tr.append("<td>" + json[i].amount + "</td>");
            tr.append("<td>" + json[i].location + "</td>");
            tr.append("<td>" + json[i].date + "</td>");
            $('#table').append(tr);
        }
    });
});

</script>

<table id= "table">
  <tr>
    <th> Name of product</th>
    <th> Category</th>
    <th> Amount</th>
    <th> Location</th>
    <th> Date</th>
  </tr>

</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: thank you so much for your answer!! i finally understand how to make a table using append instead of creating empty "boxes" in the tables.